# Handlebars for an upright seated position

Tags: handlebars

After injuring my neck, shoulder and arm on a fall from my bike I need the type of handlebar that you see more commonly on a cruiser bike.  ie that is one that gives you anupright sitting position.  My bikes are a Merida 100d and a Specialized Ariel.  Does anyone know of a handlebar the can fit these bikes.
Erin

Comment: Considering your injury, you might need a new bike. Most MTB/road bikes are designed with the idea you are going to be hunched forward, definitely not ideal for an injury like yours. If you only need a few inches, you might be able to just get new bars. For the most part they are standardized in size so it shouldn't be much of a problem finding one that fits your neck. But if not, consider getting a new neck as well! Don't risk damaging your neck (on your shoulders) any further!

Comment: First thing to do is to raise the bar.  This will likely require changing out the stem and/or adding extensions.  Try to find a new stem with less forward extension.  (Personal peeve: Cycle designs make this hard, and most non-"comfort" bikes are sold with the bar too low, because it looks "mean" and "sexy" on the showroom floor.  But the bike doesn't get ridden because it's too uncomfortable.)

Comment: (Since January of last year I'm missing two of the three tendons of my rotator cuff, but manage my touring bike with drop bars just fine.  But I changed the stem for a taller one with less extension a long time ago.)

Answer (score 5):

You can likely find bars the will fit, but keep in mind that you still want the bike to function which means moving over your shifters and brake levers. While you could probably do this as a DIY project, I'd really recommend going to a bike shop and at least getting some advice first.

The can help you select a bar that is the right diameter to fit with your current stem and talk you through issues like re-cabling (longer bars probably mean longer cables) and where/how to mount shifters and brake levers. You might end up wanting to change brake levers to a different type depending on bars.

Don't forget the you still need to be able to get on and handle the bike. You will be doing some strange things with the center of rotation for the bars. At low speed (...i.e. the speed cruiser bikes that normally have these bars), this is probably not an issue. But you get up to high speed on a decent and you might find yourself in trouble. Start slow and see how it handles.

Happy riding.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do would be swap the stem for one that gets your handlebar taller, say some 5 inches taller at least, perhaps preferrably more. This would allow you to keep your current "cockpit", with grips and levers and shifters etc.

If you don't find the taller stem (I've had a hard time finding really tall stems at the shops), I would suggest a BMX handlebar, since they get your hands much higher.

One thing to note is: when you raise your hands and torso, the body weight gets shifted so that there's less weight on the front wheel, which might affect handling making the bike a bit more unstable and prone to unwanted wheelies uphill. In this case, a BMX handlebar can be more adjustable because by rotating it in the stem you can adjust reach to get a good weight-balance and steering behaviour. The downside is the torque BMX handlebars apply on the stem, which usually is not a problem if you don't ride aggressively.

A final note on the BMX handlebar: some shifters don't fit well around the curves of the handlebar, test it before buying, if you will.

And, of course, cable and router lengths will most probably need to be replaced for longer ones.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think using a stem raiser may bring your handlebars to a position where you can ride upright. I used the  [a stem raiser](http://deltacycle.com/alloy-stem-raiser-pro) on my cycle with road-style drop bars. This helped me achieve more upright position.

This is applicable to the cycles that you have, just make sure the stem diameters match the fittings.

An alternative solution would be to use an adjustable stem, [here is an example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003KPN0LS).

These options are cheaper than getting a new handle bar setup, unless you are specifically looking to change the handle bar style. The links above are used as example only, I am not affiliated to mentioned organizations.

Comment: An alternate name for te component may be "steerer extender".